# JAXB MOXy 2.4.1 Property Overloading not working

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I have two inherited classes (`ClassTop` --> `ClassChild`) holding a data class each which have inherited properties too (`ClassTopData` --> `ClassChildData`):

**ClassTop:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class ClassTop {

    @XmlElement(name="title")
    private String title = null;

    @XmlElement(name="meta")
    private ClassTopData meta = new ClassTopData();

    public String getTitle() {return title;}
    public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}

    public ClassTopData getMeta() {return meta;}
    public void setMeta(ClassTopData meta) {this.meta = meta;}

}
```

**ClassChild extending ClassTop:**
Important: `ClassChild` has the **`property meta`** as well but with an inherited variant of `ClassTopData`:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="news")
public class ClassChild extends ClassTop {

    @XmlElement(name="childName")
    private String childName = null;

    @XmlElement(name="meta") // same property name...
    private ClassChildData meta = new ClassChildData(); //... but subclassed data 

    public String getChildName() {return childName;}
    public void setChildName(String childName) {this.childName = childName;}

    public ClassChildData getMeta() {return meta;}
    public void setMeta(ClassChildData meta) {this.meta = meta;}
}
```

And the two Data classes:

**ClassTopData**:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ClassTopData {

    private String data1 = null;
    private String data2 = null;

    public String getData1() {return data1;}
    public void setData1(String data1) {this.data1 = data1;}

    public String getData2() {return data2;}
    public void setData2(String data2) {this.data2 = data2;}

}
```

**ClassChildData**:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ClassChildData extends ClassTopData {

    private String data3 = null;

    public String getData3() {return data3;}
    public void setData3(String data3) {this.data3 = data3;}

}
```

When I marshal the ClassChild and read it back, data3 is null:

```
    ClassChild a = new ClassChild();
    a.setTitle("title");
    a.getMeta().setData1("1");
    a.getMeta().setData2("2");
    a.getMeta().setData3("3");


    // Write:
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ClassChild.class);
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    ... get some OutputStream os ...
    m.marshal(a, os);

    // Read back:
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ClassChild.class);
    Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    ... get the InputStream is ...
    ClassChild r = (ClassChild)(u.unmarshal(is));
    System.out.println("data3: "+r.getMeta().getData3());
```

And the output is

```
data3: null
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<news>
   <title>title</z:title>
   <meta>
      <data1>1</data1>
      <data2>2</data2>
      <data3>3</data3>
   </meta>
</news>
```

Comment: I also tried it without only the `@XmlRootElement` annotation (as provided in http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html). Doesn't work either, and in the XML only `data1` and `data2` gets stored.